# Package cloud_firestore has no versions that match >=0.7.0 <0.8.0 derived from

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to get the `cloud_firestore` package, which is required for this flutter tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-firebase/#7

when I run `flutter packages get` I only get back:
`Package cloud_firestore has no versions that match >=0.7.0 <0.8.0 derived from...`

The `cloud_firestore` package says on this website https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/cloud_firestore that the latest version is `0.7.2`
I tried that version as well, but I get the same error.

I've also tried the dev, master and beta channels of flutter, without any success to get this package.

And, here's my `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
name: test_app
description: Integrate firebase into flutter
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.7.0

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Any suggestions on what could be going on?
Thank you.

Comment: try running flutter clean in the console

Comment: also, I am not sure if you will need firebase_core

Comment: This is how I get the plugin, without the version `cloud_firestore:`

Comment: `flutter clean -> Deleting 'build/'.` and then `flutter packages get -> ackage cloud_firestore has no versions that match >=0.7.2 <0.8.0 derived from:`

Comment: try without the version number. Just `:`

Comment: I also sometimes got this errors, when switching from dev back to beta. I had to delete cache directory inside flutter sdk, and than run flutter upgrade again.

Comment: that seems to work! thank you (although I'm pretty sure it means that I'll keep getting the latest version, so it may not be "right" answer for a release project)

Comment: Also, there is `flutter pub cache repair`

Comment: good things to have in your quiver

Comment: actually...the app compiles (so it gets the package?) but it fails to run. lots of issues inside the `cloud_firestore` library

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172186/discussion-between-tree-and-toomanyeduardos).

Answer (score 1):

Got it "fixed", although this is not really an answer.

Tried on a second computer, and it kept giving me the same issue.

Tried on the first computer, but at a different location, and `flutter packages get` works!

So...something in the first network location was blocking the repository?

Anyways, now it works as expected. Sorry, and thank you to everyone who gave me ideas to try!

Answer (score 1):

There are docs that exist that say to include the following in your pubspec.yaml:

`firebase_firestore: ^0.12.7+1`

I believe those docs are wrong. It should be `cloud_firestore`, and the latest package versions can be found here:

https://firebaseopensource.com/projects/flutter/plugins/

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: This helped me. I wonder how one can suggest an edit to the doc that states firebase_firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Try without specifying the version just keep "cloud_firestore: ". It will automatically gets the latest version of the package. It's not adviced for production purpose as latest versions are not stable. bUt for testing purspose, it's good

Comment: with this suggestion, the app compiles, but fails to run

Comment: Run "flutter clean" in the project directory terminal/cmd. Then try to run again. It should work now.

Comment: I mentioned this in a previous comment: `flutter clean -> Deleting 'build/'.` and then `flutter packages get -> package cloud_firestore has no versions that match >=0.7.2 <0.8.0 derived from:`